# Android: how to read html files from internal storage and load in webview

Tags: java, android, html, webview

i've searched alot but nothing solves my problem. i want to build an app which reads html files from tab's internal folder. the path of html files is /file manager/device storage/Android/data/K1.html.
The problem is that the number of web pages may increase or decrease by user and i want to build the functionality that app can read all the webpages placed in that folder. i used  following code for reading file from internal storage but it doesn't point to the path. I know it is not difficult please guide me how to obtain this functionality, thanks in advance.

```
File tabFolder = getFilesDir();
String root = tabFolder.toString();
File myFile = new File(root + "/Android/data/K1.html");
    if(myFile.exists()){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "does not exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: did you set permissions in manifest file ?

Comment: yes i used this permission but it for external storage                                              <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 is there any other permission for internal storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try now...

```
String fileName = "K1.html";
String content = "K1 html file content here";
FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
try {
outputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();}

String path=getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/K1.html";
File file = new File ( path ); 
if ( file.exists() ) 
{
 // Toast File is exists
}
else
{
 // Toast File is not exists
}
```

Comment: Sorry i have to use internal storage. is it not possible to do with internal storage.

Comment: getAbsolutePath points to this path                                                                     /data/data/com.example.html/files/K1.html                                                         and the 'files' folder is empty, that is why it does not read the file because k1.html does not exist in this path.. could you please suggest me how to place file in this folder, i tried but i'm unable to paste K1.html here.

Comment: check my updated ans...

Comment: it works buddy. Thank you so much.                                                         could you please tell me how to load the html file in webview using this method webView.loadUrl("file:///" + path);

Comment: did you done with webView...?

Comment: no i was waiting for your reply

Comment: but have closed this question dear ...open again so that other can also view another answer for webview

Comment: i cannot ask more question my reputations  are low, i've unchecked your ans please edit here, i 'll accept again

Comment: ok try this now....    String path=getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/K1.html";
    File file = new File ( path ); 
    webView.loadUrl("file:///" + file);

Comment: i get this on screen "K1 html file content here"

Comment: yes that means its working....because "k1 html file content here" this is the content written in this html file....

Comment: but i want to show the web page.

Comment: do you have url of that page....